# Duplicate entry using unidirectional mapping using JoinTable

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, one-to-many

I created a JPA unidirectional join table following the JPA documentation very closely (http://www.jpox.org/docs/1_2/jpa_orm/one_to_many_list.html).

I could insert an applicant, A, with joblist (JobOne, JobTwo) without any problems. However, when I tried to insert a different applicant B, with a job already used by another applicant, e.g. joblist (JobOne), it threw an exception:

---

### 'Duplicate entry 'JobOne' for key 'jobId'

The documentation says `The join table will NOT be given a primary key (so that duplicates can be stored)` but it does not look like they use composite key (applicantId, jobId) for the join table.

```
public class Applicant
{
    private long applicantId;
    private List<Job> jobList;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinTable(name="applicant_job",
     joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="applicantId")},
     inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="jobId")})
 public List<Job> getJobList() {
  return jobList;
 }
     //getters, setters
}


public class Job
{
     private long jobId;
     //getters, setters
}
```

Comment: I'm adding it to the original posting.